# Russian in link_to in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, character-encoding

I am having trouble using Russian in link_to... RoR displays some bad chars...

Encoding is UTF-8 (in db and database.yml and application.rb)

more info:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8):
       2:   <%= v.theme %><br />
       3: <% end %>
       4:   
       5: <%= link_to 'Проверка', :controller=>'blog', :action=>'list' %>
     app/views/blog/list.html.erb:5:in    `_app_views_blog_list_html_erb__213318138_91664950_691435151'
```

Comment: ruby and rails versions?

Comment: try using latin1 in place of utf-8... thanks....